# Class method like addays from Date

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I am doing a variation of **Date Class**, because I need to work with abnormal dates (eg. 2016-14-31) (accountig purposes), so, I want to recreate some of the basic methods like AddDays(), AddMonths(), AddYear.

Lets suppose that I want do subtract a day, from one of my custom dates:

```
date1 as new DataManager("2016-14-31")

date2 as DataManager

date2=date1.adddays(-1)
```

How can I pass date1 to addays method, to subtract a day and return it to date2?

Not an expert, but i'm just curious, and it could make easy some of my work.

Comment: ID your new date class is REALLY a class, then just add AddDays() as public Sub of the class...

Comment: `How can i pass date1 to addays method`  The way you show it - and for the NET DateTime Type (which is a structure) - `AddDays` is a method.  If Date1 is an instance of your special date type, then `AddDays` would be a method on it.  You'd be better off writing a converter than trying to write a new class.

Comment: Days are added and subtracted using the concept of an "epoch",  An epoch is some date, typically in the past and all dates are represented internally as the number of days since that date.  I believe that the epoch in .net is Jan 1 of the year 0.  So how many days are there between Jan 1, 0000 and "2016-14-31"?  Does every year have 14 months?  You'll have to define how your "abnormal" calendar works.

Comment: So it doesn't worth it... :( Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Just need to create a function in your DataManager Class that returns a newly calculated DataManager like this:

```
Public Function AddDays(ByVal iDays As Integer) As DataManager

    Dim NewlyCalculatedDataManager As DataManager = New DataManager()
    'Do you addition here using current instance information then assign to NewlyCalculatedDataManager

    Return NewlyCalculatedDataManager 'here

End Function
```